# Apex Class Error Message: System.JSONException: No content to map to Object due to end of input

Tags: apex, json, deserialize

I am getting an Error in Apex when i try to Deserialize the JSON Response.
System.JSONException: No content to map to Object due to end of input

My JSON Response in debug Log is:
[{"recId":"1"},{"recId":"2"}]

My Apex Class is :

```
public with sharing class myvalues {

 @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
 public static List<String> thisvalue(String searchKey , String selrec){
 system.debug('The value is '+selrec);
    If(selrec != null || selrec != ''){
    List<String> f = (List<String>) JSON.deserialize(selrec, 
      List<String>.class);
     system.debug('value of List is '+f);

     }
  }
}
```

What Am I missing Here?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your error is that `selrec` is not a list of strings, in Json terms, it is a list of objects, a list of strings would be `["abc","def"]`

You need something like this:

```
class SelectRecord {
  String recId;
}

and then

  @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
  public static List<String> thisvalue(String searchKey , String selrec){
    system.debug('The value is '+selrec);
    If(String.isNotBlank(selRec)){
      List<SelectRecord> selectedRecs = (List<SelectRecord>) JSON.deserialize(selrec, 
         List<SelectRecord>.class);
      system.debug('value of List is '+selectedRecs);

    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi cropredy. Thank You so much for explaining and it does make sense but  I am still getting the same error after I change with your logic. Also I have changed the JSON response to : [{"recId":"abc"},{"recId":"def"}]

Comment: what does `selRec` look like in the debug statement once the method is entered?

Comment: cropredy, the debug Statement is : The value is [{"recId":"abc"},{"recId":"def"}], I am doing JSON.Stringify in LWC javascript and then is getting this String

Comment: Hi cropredy, I have made some changes and have posted the same question here with some changes in Apex where I am getting the values if I hardcode the JSON to deserialize Vs dynamically getting the values 
  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/283715/apex-error-message-json-exception-error-no-content-to-map