# Apex Error Message : JSON Exception Error: No content to Map

Tags: apex, json, deserialize

The previous Question is linked here:
[Apex Class Error Message: System.JSONException: No content to map to Object due to end of input](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/283448/apex-class-error-message-system-jsonexception-no-content-to-map-to-object-due)

I have updated the code 
If I use the below code where String is Dynamic, I am getting the above error but when I hard code the values, I get the response

In debug Logs the value of selrec is : [{"recId":"abc"},{"recId":"def"}]
Code Generating the error:

```
public with sharing class getmypicklistvalues{        
 @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<String> fetchPickListValue(String searchKey , String selrec){
system.debug('The value is selected'+selrec);
List<String> pickListValuesList= new List<String>();
 If(selrec != NULL  || String.isNotBlank(selRec)){
  List<Object> selectedvalues = (List<Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(selrec);
for(Object slval: selectedvalues){    
    Map<String,Object> data = (Map<String,Object>)slval;
    system.debug('The value of Object is'+data.get('recId'));
    }
   }
  }
}
```

But when I hardcode the values to Deserialize the JSON response, I am getting the desired result.

```
public with sharing class getmypicklistvalues{        
 @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<String> fetchPickListValue(String searchKey , String selrec){
system.debug('The value is selected'+selrec);
List<String> pickListValuesList= new List<String>();
 If(selrec != NULL  || String.isNotBlank(selRec)){
  List<Object> selectedvalues = (List<Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped('[{"recId":"Angio Detect"},{"recId":"Animana Data Conversion"}]');
for(Object slval: selectedvalues){    
    Map<String,Object> data = (Map<String,Object>)slval;
    system.debug('The value of Object is'+data.get('recId'));
    }
   }
  }
}
```

I am not sure what I am missing here. FYI selrec will be NULL initially and the values will be loaded once users makes a selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace line `If(selrec != NULL  || String.isNotBlank(selRec)){`

with

```
If(String.isNotBlank(selRec)){
```

The problem is occurring when `selrec` is null so you need to handle that.

See below code fire error.

```
String selrec = '';
List<Object> selectedvalues = (List<Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(selrec);
for(Object slval: selectedvalues){    
    Map<String,Object> data = (Map<String,Object>)slval;
    system.debug('The value of Object is '+data.get('recId'));
}
```

But the code below does not.

```
String selrec = '[{"recId":"abc"},{"recId":"def"}]';
List<Object> selectedvalues = (List<Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(selrec);
for(Object slval: selectedvalues){    
    Map<String,Object> data = (Map<String,Object>)slval;
    system.debug('The value of Object is '+data.get('recId'));
}
```

So you need to add null check before parsing.

Comment: String.isNotBlank handles null and empty string; no need to test for null

Comment: I have updated the code, thanks @cropredy

Comment: Thank you so much Rahul and cropredy, changing :  If(selrec != NULL || String.isNotBlank(selRec)){        TO         If(selrec != NULL && String.isNotBlank(selRec)){   works like a charm . I think I should quit programming an go to Himalaya if I am going to ask these kind of stupid questions. Thanks Again